# If $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }a_{n}=a$ then $\left\{a_{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\right\} \cup \left\{ a\right\}$ is compact

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

- If $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }a_{n}=a$ then $\left\{a_{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\right\} \cup \left\{ a\right\}$ is compact.

**I couldn't  do anything. Can you give a hint?**

Note: in the question $a_n\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: First, the set is bounded. Second, prove that its complement is open.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco if its complement is open, then how can we say the set is compact?

Comment: @AlexFrancisco Hah! Closed and bounded sets are compact.

Comment: Wait why are we assuming $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$? Convergence makes sense in any metric space so this assumption really doesn't seem justified...

Comment: @mathworker21 in the question $a_n\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $X$ be an open cover of $\{ a_n \mid n \in \Bbb N \} \cup \{a\}$.

Then, there is an open set containing $a$, called $X_a$.

Since $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = a$, $X_a$ must contain all but finitely many members of $\{ a_n \mid n \in \Bbb N \}$.

Then, pick the open sets containing those finitely many members, and together with $X_a$ you obtain a finite subcover of $\{ a_n \mid n \in \Bbb N \} \cup \{a\}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Prove that $\{a_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{a\}$ is closed and bounded

Comment: Wait why are we assuming $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$? Convergence makes sense in any metric space so this assumption really doesn't seem justified...

Comment: in the question $a_n\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It wasn't given when this answer was written.

Comment: @mathworker21 I assume that for the tag "real-analysis." But, if this is not the case, you are rigth.

Comment: How can I show $\left\{a_{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\right\} \cup \left\{ a\right\}$ is bounded?

Comment: @Kahler Every convergent sequence is bounded. If you need, I can write the proof.

Comment: @Gödel I am confused by your comment and even more confused why it was upvoted. Every single real analysis text I know (and trust me, I know a lot) does things over general metric spaces.

Comment: I could't show that the set is closed. Can you help?

Comment: @Kahler Hint: The set is closed if it contains all its limits points.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Compactness is equivalent to sequential compactness in metric spaces. Given any sequence $(b_n)$ with terms from $S = \{a_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{a\}$, there are two cases - either the sequence only uses finitely many values from $S$ or infinitely many of them. Can you find a convergent subsequence in either case?