# Show that $\left\{a_{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\right\} \cup \left\{ a\right\}$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $a_n$ be a sequence in set of real numbers. Assume $a_n$ converges to $a$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Show that $\left\{a_{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\right\} \cup \left\{ a\right\}$ is closed

**Recall**. $X\in\mathbb{R}$ is closed if and only if the complement of $X$ is open.

Let $X=\left\{a_{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\right\} \cup \left\{ a\right\}$ be a set.

I need to show that $X^c$ is open. Let $t\in X^c$. Then, $t\not\in X$.

So what should I do?

Comment: It seems that you asked this here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2596457/if-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-a-n-a-then-left-a-nn-in-mathbbn-right?rq=1. In fact this shows compactness which is stronger.

Comment: @Dave I know, but I only couldn't show the set is closed. Can you help?

Comment: By Heine-Borel, we know that (since $X\subseteq\Bbb R$) $X$ is compact if and only if $X$ is closed and bounded. In your other question, you receive an answer which proves that $X$ is compact. Thus, $X$ must be closed.

Comment: @Dave No... No... no... in the question, we don't know the set is compact. I want to show complement of the set is open. Can you help for only this?

Comment: Considering the problem deals with a particular metric space, the first link in the comments is actually helpful.

Comment: For any convergent sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ of real (or complex) numbers; the range of the sequence union the limit of the sequence is compact in the topology induced by the Euclidean Metric on $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$), because it is closed and bounded (Heine-Borel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $(a_n)$ is convergent, therefore it is bounded. Thus, there exists $M>0$ such that $|a_n| \leq M$ for all $n \in \mathbb N.$ As $a_n \to a,$ so we also have that $|a| \leq M$. We thus have, $$X\subseteq [-M,M]\\(-\infty,-M)\cup (M,\infty) \subseteq X^c.$$

**Case $1: t<-M.$** Then $t \in (-\infty,-M) \subseteq X^c.$

**Case $2: t>M.$** Then $t \in (M,\infty)\subseteq X^c.$

**Case $3: t \in [-M,M].$** Let $\epsilon_1=|a-t|>0.$ Since, $a_n \to a,$ therefore, there exists $n_0\in \mathbb N$ such that $|a_n-a|<\frac{\epsilon_1}{2}$ for all $n \geq n_0.$ Let $\epsilon_2= \min_{n<n_0}|a_n-t|>0$ and $\epsilon=\frac{\min \{\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2\}}{2}.$ Then $t \in (t-\epsilon,t+\epsilon)\subseteq X^c.$

It follows that $X^c$ is open.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\{ a_n : n\in \mathbb N \} \cup \{ a\}$.

For any $x\in \mathbb R \backslash A$, let $\epsilon = |x-a|>0$.

Since $a_n \rightarrow a$, there exists an $N$ such that for all $n> N$, 
$|a_n -a|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Let $\delta = \min \{ \frac{\epsilon}{2}, |x-a_1|, \cdots, |x-a_N|\}$. Then open ball $\{s\in \mathbb R: |x-s|<\delta\}\subset \mathbb R\backslash A$.